# Selector (CSS or Xpath) for an item

Tags: python, html, css, xpath, scrapy

http://www.dickssportinggoods.com/p/puma-mens-evospeed-35-leather-fg-soccer-cleats-16pummvspd35lthfgnth/16pummvspd35lthfgnth?&color=White/Orange&Clearance=true

I'd like to get the "Cleats" item, as seen in the picture below:
[image]

My unsucessful attempt:

```
response.xpath('.//*[@class="cat-breadcrumb"]/span/@itemprop').extract_first()
'item'
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
'normalize-space(id("WC_BreadCrumb_Link_4")/span/text())'
```

Comment: i see, Thanks a lot